# When using cookies in okhttp3 does a CookieJar have any performance benefits over an Interceptor?

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit, okhttp

I know that there are basically two ways to save a cookie in okhttp3:-

```
Using an Interceptor with Sharedpreferences
Or a CookieJar implementation with SharedPreferences.
```

However, what I don't know is which of these operations is more *expensive*

Intuitively it seems as though calling an Interceptor that passes through `SharedPreferences` might be more *expensive* but I'm not sure that a `CookieJar` passing through `SharedPreferences` would be any different.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With cookies you are going to need to look at them on every inbound and outgoing request which is exactly what an interceptor does. However, remember that cookies can be quite complex when related to https only, domains, expirations. In this sense the CookieJar might actually be slower because it will handle everything for you but its well worth it.

Here is an example using a cookie jar with OkHttp 3

```
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar;

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
JavaNetCookieJar cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(cookieJar).build();
```

Comment: it requires this
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:XXX'

Answer (score 1):

The performance differences are negligible. You should probably use a CookieJar because it lets OkHttp do more of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I initially started out with the interceptors and yeah the cookieJar turned out to be a lot better - everything went in on one class and it reduced a lot of the repetition.